How do I update parent component after deletion of one item in a nested component?
I am using Angular 18 and I have this scenario:

The DataService handles HTTP requests using HttpClient:
export class DataService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getAll() {}
  deleteOne() {}
}


The DataComponent is a wrapper which uses the DataService to retrieve the data and display it:
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Data[] = []
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.getAll().subscribe(data => { this.data = data }
  }
}


Inside the DataComponent I render FooComponent which receives a single Data instance:
@for ( item of data; track $index ) {
  <FooComponent [item]="item" />
}


Inside the FooComponent I render ItemActions component:
<h1>{{ item.name }}</h1>
<item-actions [item]="item" />


The ItemActions component holds some buttons and one of them is the delete button, which would trigger the deleteOne() method of the DataService:
export class ItemActions {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}
  onDelete( id: string ) {
    this.dataService.deleteOne(id)
  }
}



The backend works fine, the HTTP DELETE request is performed, but the frontend is not updated accordingly.
Some ideas I have:

I think the problem could be solved with RxJS but since I am new on the topic, I cannot understand how. I would really appreciate a suggestion on this topic and eventually a very good RxJS tutorial applied to Angular.

I was thinking about EventEmitter, but in this case I should emit something to the DataComponent to suggest that something was deleted and therefore refresh the page. But if I have very deep nesting, then this would be a very long chain of emitters.

I think I could also use ChangeDetectorRef, but I'd prefer the RxJS approach to handle the problem.



You were on the right path with your second idea.
In order to ensure your frontend is up-to-date you need to notify the topmost component that the data changed. While it is possible (and sometimes even better) to trigger that notification via the observable returned from the DataService.getAll(), the usual solution is to make only the topmost component manage the data. This is how it's done:
// let's say this is the topmost component for our data model
// which could represent e.g. a page containing multiple sections
@Component({
  selector: "app-data-page",
  template: `
    <app-data-list [items]="datas$ | async" (deleted)="delete($event)" />
  `
})
export class DataPageComponent implements OnInit {
  // then this is the only component that works with the data service
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  // by the way, it's simpler to work with raw observables and the AsyncPipe
  datas$: Observable<Data[]>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.datas$ = this.dataService.getAll();
  }

  delete(data: Data): void {
    this.dataService.deleteOne(data.id).subscribe(() => {
      // reload the data on successful deletion
      this.datas$ = this.dataService.getAll();
    });
  }
}

// all the other components do not use the data service;
// they only accept data via inputs and communicate events upwards via outputs
@Component({
  selector: "app-data-list",
  template: `
    @for (item of items; track $index) {
      <app-data-item [item]="item" (deleted)="deleted.emit(item)" />
    }
  `,
  // since the component does not rely on anything but its inputs
  // we can apply the OnPush change detection strategy
  // making the component more performant
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DataListComponent {
  @Input()
  items: Data[];

  @Output()
  readonly deleted = new EventEmitter<Data>();
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-data-item",
  template: `
    <h1>{{ item.name }}</h1>
    <app-data-item-actions [item]="item" (deleted)="deleted.emit()" />
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DataItemComponent {
  @Input()
  item: Data;

  @Output()
  readonly deleted = new EventEmitter<void>();
}

@Component({
  selector: "app-data-item",
  template: `
    <button (click)="deleted.emit()">Delete</button>
  `,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DataItemActionsComponent {
  @Input()
  item: Data;

  @Output()
  readonly deleted = new EventEmitter<void>();
}

Now, this might look like a lot of unnecessary duplication. However, the benefits of this approach are:

data management is localized in one single component, so it's much easier to work with the data;
all the other components are reusable: they don't depend on the source of the data, so it's trivial to e.g. display multiple app-data-list of different items or to use app-data-item-actions somewhere else in the application;
all these components are also easily testable: they are decoupled, free of side-effects and less complex;
all these components work with the OnPush change detection which means way less rendering and therefore more performance.

Read more about the approach also known as "smart and dumb components".

But isn't it an old way to handle this scenario? Isn't there a modern way, I mean with Angular 17+? And also, let's suppose that I have this delete in a completely another component, in which I can't use the EventEmitter. How could I then solve the problem?

Thanks to skink's answer I could go through different articles about smart and dumb components. Actually what I was looking for relies in BehaviorSubject of RxJS: by creating an additional service, we can notify the DataComponent that an action was performed, without worrying about that it is far away from the relation parent-child. Not sure about the over-using of this approach, but in my case it seems to work fine.
